# Simple random walk on a discrete torus - the eigensystem, reference

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, random-walks, spectral-graph-theory, eigenvector

My problem concerns finding a reference in which the formulae for the eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors ($n$ linearly independent eigenvectors!) for the transition matrix of a simple symmetric random walk on a discrete torus $(\mathbb{Z}/n)$ are given; in particular, I'm looking for a reference with the formula $(\star \star)$ below. Let me elaborate a bit more on my problem.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. A simple symmetric random walk on a discrete torus $(\mathbb{Z}/n)$ has the transition matrix $P = [p_{ij}]_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$ given by
$$ p_{ij} = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2} & \mbox{ if } j \equiv i+1 \ ( \!\!\mod n) \\\frac{1}{2} & \mbox{ if } j \equiv i-1 \ (\! \!\mod n)  \\0 & \mbox{otherwise} 
 \end{cases}.$$

It is easy to show (*cf*. Section 12.3, Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions of Some Simple Random Walks, in D. A. Levin, Y. Peres, and E. L. Wilmer, **Markov chains and mixing times**. *American Mathematical Society*,
Providence, RI, 2009 that can be accessed from http://yuvalperes.com/) that the eigenvalues of $P$ are given by
$$ \lambda_k = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n} \right)$$
and the corresponding eigenvectors $v_k = (v_k(0), \ldots, v_k(n-1))^T$are given by 
$$(\star) \ \qquad v_k(j) = \cos \left(\frac{2\pi jk }{n} \right) $$
for $k$, $j \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$.

However, $\lambda_k = \lambda_{n-k}$ and similarly $v_k = v_{n-k}$, so from the above result we do not obtain the full system of eigenvectors, that is, the set $\{ v_0, \ldots, v_{n-1}\}$ is linearly dependent and, in particular, it spans a $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor +1$ dimensional vector space.

Furthermore, we have that $P$ has $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor +1$ distinct eigenvalues, and for even $n$ only $\lambda_0=1$ and $\lambda_{\frac{n}{2}}=-1$ have multiplicity $1$ the other eigenvalues have multiplicity $2$, for odd $n$ only $\lambda_0=1$ has multiplicity $1$ and the other eigenvalue have multiplicity $2$.

One may show that if we replace formula $(\star)$ with
$$(\star \star) \qquad v_k(j) = \cos \left( \frac{k(4j-1)}{2n}\pi\right)$$
then we obtain $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors which correspond to $\lambda_k$ for $k \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$.

I strongly suspect that this result is also known, but I cannot find any references to it. I would appreciate if someone could provide me with a reference.

Comment: Using character theory the complex eigenvectors are $v_k(j)=e^{2\pi jk/n}$. Now you need to turn these into real eigenvectors. Note in your case k,n-k have the same eigenvalue $\lambda_k$.

Comment: This probably should be in Diaconis monograph on group representations and statistics or  Harmonic Analysis on Finite Groups
Representation Theory, Gelfand Pairs and Markov Chains by Silberstein et al

Comment: Your eigenvectors are picking up what was lost by forgetting the imaginary parts.